# How to assign geometry_msgs / Pose of ROS under arduino circumstances

Tags: ros, pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Pose.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;

geometry_msgs::Pose pose_msgs;
ros::Publisher pose("pose",&pose_msgs);

void setup(){
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  //Serial.begin(9600);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(pose);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  pose_msgs = {[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]};
  pose.publish(&pose_msgs);
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1000);
}
```

My answer:How to assign geometry_msgs / Pose of ROS under arduino circumstances?

---

Edit:  How to assign geometry_msgs / Pose of ROS under arduino circumstances?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222213/how-to-assign-geometry_msgs-/-pose-of-ros-under-arduino-circumstances/) by [hua](https://answers.ros.org/users/25282/hua/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-12-09

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-12-09**:
Please add a question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the message doc [here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose.html)

Afaik, there is no difference between arduino or regular C++ in this case.
Do something along the lines of

```
pose_msg.position.x = 1.0
pose_msg.position.y = 2.0
pose_msg.position.z = 3.0
pose_msg.orientation.x = 4.0
pose_msg.orientation.y = 5.0
pose_msg.orientation.z = 6.0
pose_msg.orientation.w = 7.0
```

But make sure, that your quaternion is normalized, which it isn't in the example above!
Also, check again the [documentation of how to set up your publishers](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)). What you have there is not correct....

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0